# Delete object from list in another class

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and have come to the problem that I do not know how I can get "access" to the "setPeople" from the List.js class.
The GUI looks as followed. [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JG1C.png)

I know how to handle this if I would just do all of it in one class (App.js for example). But by doing it the "clean" way, I can't get the desired solution.

I guess I have to declare the "const [people, setPeople] = useState(data) somewhere else, right?

List.js:

```
const List = ({ people }) => {
      const deletePerson = (id) => {
        let newPeople = people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);
        console.log(newPeople);
        // setPeople(newPeople); // ***how can I access this setPeople method in order to update the list?***
      };
      return (
        <>
          {people.map((person) => {
            const { id, name, age, image } = person;
            return (
              <article key={id} className="person">
                <img src={image} alt={name} />
                <div>
                  <h4>{name}</h4>
                  <p>{age}</p>
                  <button
                    className="btn"
                    onClick={() => {
                      deletePerson({ id });
                    }}
                  >
                    Delete me (HERE)
                  </button>
                </div>
              </article>
            );
          })}
        </>
      );
    };
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data); //data is just an array of objects
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>{people.length} birthdays today</h3>
        <List people={people}></List>
        <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}>Clear all</button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a callback `onDeletePerson` prop on your `List` component:

```
const List = ({ people, onDeletePerson }) => {
      const deletePerson = (id) => {
        let newPeople = people.filter((person) => person.id !== id);
        console.log(newPeople);
        onDeletePerson(newPeople);
      };
  ...
};
```

and then, in your `App` component, you retrieve the callback value

```
function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data); //data is just an array of objects
  const handleOnDeletePerson = (value) => {
     setPeople(value);
  };
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>{people.length} birthdays today</h3>
        <List people={people} onDeletePerson={handleOnDeletePerson}></List>
        <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}>Clear all</button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Another way would be to use a state management library such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `List` component an `onDelete` event handler props, it will be triggered when the user clicks the delete button.

Controls the `people` state in the `App` component, and `List` is more like a pure UI component, does not include business logic.

`App.js`:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import List from "./List";

export default function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "a", age: 20, image: "" },
    { id: 2, name: "b", age: 20, image: "" },
    { id: 3, name: "c", age: 20, image: "" }
  ]);
  return (
    <main>
      <section className="container">
        <h3>{people.length} birthdays today</h3>
        <List
          people={people}
          onDelete={({ id }) => {
            setPeople((pre) => pre.filter((person) => person.id !== id));
          }}
        ></List>
        <button onClick={() => setPeople([])}>Clear all</button>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}
```

`List.js`:

```js
import React from "react";

const List = ({ people, onDelete }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const { id, name, age, image } = person;
        return (
          <article key={id} className="person">
            <img src={image} alt={name} />
            <div>
              <h4>{name}</h4>
              <p>{age}</p>
              <button
                className="btn"
                onClick={() => {
                  onDelete({ id });
                }}
              >
                Delete me (HERE)
              </button>
            </div>
          </article>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-goldberg-h5bj8?file=/src/App.js:0-689)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options to achieve that

1. Pass `setPeople` in props to `List`
2. Use React.Context and have `setPeople` in the context, use `React.useContext` hook to access to the context in `List`
3. Use global state (with Redux for example) and you can connect to the shared store in components you need, and dispatch `setPeople` from anywhere